# how to get time difference in hour:minute:seconds in string format

Tags: datetime, vb6, timespan

```
I have two times values, such as:   
1) 2:00:00 PM 
2) 5:30:10 PM
```

I want to get time difference in HH:MM:SS.  Here is what I tried:

```
lMinutes = DateDiff("n", CStr(TimeValue(RPTRs(2))), CStr(TimeValue(RPTRs(3))))
lHours = Fix(lMinutes / 60) '
lMinutes = ((lMinutes / 60) - lHours) * 60
```

How can I calculate seconds?

I also want to concatenate the results as follows:

```
sTimeDiff = " & Format$(lHours,"00") &  :" & Format$(lMinutes, "00") & ":" & Format$(lSeconds, "00")
```

Answer (score 1):

yes ,,i have resolved this my answer is :

```
Dim mHours As Long, mMinutes As Long, mSeconds As Long, sTimeDiff As String, lSeconds As Long
lSeconds = DateDiff("s", CStr(TimeValue(RPTRs(2))), CStr(TimeValue(RPTRs(3))))
mSeconds = lSeconds ' Sample data
mHours = mSeconds \ 3600
mMinutes = (mSeconds - (mHours * 3600)) \ 60
mSeconds = mSeconds - ((mHours * 3600) + (mMinutes * 60))
sTimeDiff = mHours & ":" & mMinutes & ":" & mSeconds
```

Comment: Did you still want the leading zeros?   `sTimeDiff = Right("00" & mHours,2) & ":" & Right("00" & mMinutes, 2) & ":" & Right("00" & mSeconds, 2)`